# Impresspages 4 jquery javascript trouble (.redy function)

Tags: javascript, jquery, impresspages

I am developing a plugin and I have tasks performed in `$(document).ready(function()` In admin environment and even in preview way the implementation working perfectly. However, in 'standalone' approach (system unlogged), the function `$(document).ready(function()` isn't executed and this section of the new plugin won't start. 
Has anyone an idea to solve this? 
Thanks!

Comment: What do you see when you trace the jQuery code?

Comment: my `.ready `  isn't executed in 'standalone' environment. In admin side and in preview it is. In standalone the the `console.log()` isn't 'printed'.

Comment: Where exactly you put your code? And how that JavaScript file is added for printing? Looks like that you include that file only in admin mode.

Comment: The code is added for both - admin and site. The `.ready` call a function that create pagination for the plugin. In the admin and preview working fine. But in **standalone** this `,ready` not even executed. Nor the `console.log()` debug is broadcast, demonstrating the function not run. I have also tested out of the environment the pagination code against **ipCore.min.js** It's all right. In short, **admin** and **preview**, working well (so, the code is right). In standalone the `.ready` doesn't called. So...

Comment: Finally, the **js** files and the **script** text are evidently and appropriately put in **Event** class/file like determined by the impresspages. So...